# difference between ./test.pl and perl test.pl

Tags: linux, perl

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I/root/Lib/ 
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@INC;
```

The above code file name is test.pl and the permission is 755.

When I am running the program using /usr/bin/perl test.pl the output of the @INC contains "/root/Lib"  at the end. It is like push in to @INC.

/usr/bin/perl test.pl Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          '/etc/perl',
          '/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0',
          '/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0',
          '/usr/lib/perl5',
          '/usr/share/perl5',
          '/usr/lib/perl/5.10',
          '/usr/share/perl/5.10',
          '/usr/local/lib/site_perl',
          '.',
          '/root/Lib/'
        ];
```

But when I am running the program using ./test.pl the output of the @INC contain "/root/Lib/" contain first as well as end also. It is like unshift and push.

./test.pl output

```
$VAR1 = [
          '/root/Lib/',
          '/etc/perl',
          '/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0',
          '/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0',
          '/usr/lib/perl5',
          '/usr/share/perl5',
          '/usr/lib/perl/5.10',
          '/usr/share/perl/5.10',
          '/usr/local/lib/site_perl',
          '.',
          '/root/Lib/'
        ];
```

So I want to know what is the difference between ./test.pl and /usr/bin/perl test.pl ?

Comment: +1 that's surprising behaviour, investigating...

Comment: if you did perl -I/root/Lib test.pl it would be the same. The shebang on line one is used as the command when you do ./test.pl

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser: if `L` is `/root/lib` I get output of `L, L, ...` for the shebang execution and `L, ...` for the /usr/bin/perl invocation. What OS and (if applicable) perl package are you using?

Comment: Also, the values (if any) the environment variables of PERL5LIB and PERLLIB are relevant.

Comment: Do you have multiple perl installations?

Comment: See also [What is the difference between "`perl test.pl`" and "`./test.pl`"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970541/what-is-the-difference-between-perl-test-pl-and-test-pl).  Not identical, but closely related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two questions lurking here.  The headline question is "What's the difference between `./test.pl` and `perl test.pl`?", while the secondary question is "Why is `/root/Lib` added at the front of `@INC` when the script is run as `./test.pl` and not when run as `perl test.pl`?"

An answer, not necessarily applicable to your situation, is that `./test.pl` runs the Perl interpreter specified by the shebang (`/usr/bin/perl`), whereas `perl test.pl` runs whatever Perl interpreter is found first on your `$PATH` (or aliases or functions).  These need not be the same version of Perl.  For me, they very seldom are the same version of Perl; the one in `/usr/bin` is usually relatively old and the one on my `$PATH` is relatively new (5.8.x vs 5.18.x, for example).

Working with Perl 5.12.4 (ouch; that's old) from `/usr/bin` on my machine, and using your script, I see:

```
$ perl test.pl
$VAR1 = [
          '/root/Lib/',
          '/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level',
          '/Library/Perl/5.12',
          '/Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level',
          '/Network/Library/Perl/5.12',
          '/Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4',
          '/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level',
          '/System/Library/Perl/5.12',
          '/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level',
          '/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12',
          '.'
        ];
$ ./test.pl
$VAR1 = [
          '/root/Lib/',
          '/root/Lib/',
          '/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level',
          '/Library/Perl/5.12',
          '/Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level',
          '/Network/Library/Perl/5.12',
          '/Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4',
          '/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level',
          '/System/Library/Perl/5.12',
          '/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level',
          '/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12',
          '.'
        ];
$
```

Note that here the `/root/Lib` name is added once or twice to `@INC`. My best guess is that when you use `perl test.pl`, Perl scans the shebang and adds the `-I` option if finds there.  When you use `./test.pl`, the kernel runs `/usr/bin/perl -I/root/Lib test.pl` (where we can negotiation on whether the name `test.pl` appears on the command line; the key point is that the `-I/root/Lib` does appear), so Perl adds `/root/Lib` once because of the explicit `-I` provided by the kernel, and then adds another because it parses the shebang line.

See: [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for many more details.

Answer (score 2):

You should `use lib` instead. That way, execution is consistent.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use lib qw( /root/Lib/ );

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@INC;
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html

Answer (score 2):

When you run it as `perl test.pl`, among the first things it does is look to see if there is a line starting with `#!`. If it finds one it tries to act as if it were called with those arguments.

So the following adds warnings

```
#! perl -w
```

If you run it as `./test.pl` your system actually runs it with those arguments. Perl really doesn't have a way of knowing that it was called implicitly like that. So Perl just parses that line itself like it did previously.

In your case that means that `/root/Lib/` will be added to [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40INC) twice.

The reason it appears at the beginning of the list; is that when Perl is actually called with that option, it adds it before it has a chance to load '[`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40INC) with anything.
If it gets added when parsing `#!`, it has already populated [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40INC) so it adds it at the end.