# Expect command not found in script

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I have installed expect command on CentOS 7 with `yum install expect -y`. I want to automate some input in my script but it seems like it doesn't interpret in bash anymore.

Here is my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
homeDir="/home"

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    CLIENT="$1"
    ./easyrsa build-client-full "$CLIENT" nopass
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    CLIENT="$1"
    password="$2"
    set timeout -1
    spawn ./easyrsa build-client-full "$CLIENT"
    expect "Enter PEM pass phrase:"
    send -- "$password"
    expect eof
else
    echo "script <username> <password (optional)>"
fi
```

I made the script executable with `chmod +x script` and run it like `./script`.
The error I get :

> script: line11: spawn : command not found couldn't read file "Enter
>   PEM pass phrase:": no such file or directory 
>   script: ligne13: send :
>   command not found couldn't read file "eof": no such file or
>   directory

If I make `whereis expect`

I get :

```
expect: /usr/bin/expect /usr/share/man/man1/expect.1.gz
```

I would like to ask if there is some alternative without using another lib ?

I also tried using this line of code but this doesn't give any return :

```
echo "$password" | ./easyrsa build-client-full "$CLIENT"
```

Comment: Your shebang is `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`. So the command in the script will not be interpreted by `bash`, but by `expect` when you run it with `./`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the #! shebang work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009192/how-does-the-shebang-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want an `expect` script inside a `bash` script something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

homeDir="/home"

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    CLIENT="$1"
    ./easyrsa build-client-full "$CLIENT" nopass
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    CLIENT="$1"
    password="$2"
    /usr/bin/expect <<EOF
    ...
    DO EXPECT STUFF
    ...
EOF
else
    echo "script <username> <password (optional)>"
fi
```

Comment: Doing in this way I have an error of permission. `:awk: fatal : impossible to open file « ... »`

Comment: Not sure what you have done, but AFAIK there is no `awk` in the script I suggest.

Comment: I think it's beacause the script I call (`./easyrsa`) doesn't have enought permission if I run throught expect

Comment: Maybe click `edit` under your original question and paste in the code you are now running too.

Comment: I'm not the author of the script `./easyrsa`, and this script it self call another one

Comment: I also tried using code like `echo "$password" | ./easyrsa build-client-full "$CLIENT"`

Comment: Sorry, I can neither see what you are running at the top-level, nor what it is calling at the lower level. I can only suggest you turn on debugging, so instead of `./easyrsa` try running `bash -x ./easyrsa`

Comment: I have the error because the script `easyrsa` doesn't generate the certificate