# Array split from string is not working in bash

Tags: bash, go

I have a bash script in which I am receiving response of an api in string format. The response is in the following format:

foo bar test stack over flow

Now I am having following bash script to convert it to array and process further:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$(curl "API URL")
resp=($result)
for i in "${resp[@]}"
do
    echo "$i" 
done
```

**Problem:**

If I run this script manually in the terminal (by making it executable) it works fine. But when I try to run it by using Golang sh command

```
ExecuteCommand("sh /path/to/directory/test.sh")

func ExecuteCommand(command string) error{
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c",command)
    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr

    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
    return nil
}
```

It gives me error:

```
test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

can someone help me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: sh != bash. Try with `/bin/bash /path/to/directory/test.sh`

Comment: Using `sh` to run a script overrides the shebang. Make it executable, and then run it just by specifying its path (`/path/to/directory/test.sh`) so that the shebang gets properly respected.

Comment: you can also probably simply do `bash /path/to/directory/test.sh` instead of `sh /path/to/directory/test.sh`

Comment: I have updated my question for complete requirement. Apology for the incomplete details!

Comment: @Amandeepkaur : Why do you do `sh` in `ExecuteCommand("sh /path/to/directory/test.sh")` if `sh` is already in `cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c",command)` + why don't you try with `bash` instead of `sh` + if your file can be executed, why don't you just execute it instead of using `sh` ?

Comment: Be aware that you can also consume your API using directly Golang

Comment: @CorentinLimier can you tell me why this gives error while splitting from string ?

Comment: @Amandeepkaur simply because your `sh` is probably pointing to `dash` or any other version that does not support bash arrays.

Comment: on my os, `bash -c 'a=("hello" "world")'` works and `dash -c 'a=("hello" "world")'` doesn't and raises `dash: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: @Amandeepkaur, because you're executing your script with sh, which isn't necessarily the same as bash (it symlinks to dash on many distros by default). You can't use bash features such as arrays in other shells.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept @Vorsprung's answer that should work too (if your bash file is executable). Btw, I voted to reopen the question, I don't understand why it is considered as off-topic

Answer (score 1):

change these lines in your example

```
ExecuteCommand("/path/to/directory/test.sh")

func ExecuteCommand(command string) error{
    cmd := exec.Command(command)
```

The [kernel shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009192/how-does-the-shebang-work/3009280) will intercept the #! line and correctly run the script

Answer (score 1):

U can also create a shortcut from "test.sh" file :

```
#!/bin/bash
$ sudo ln -s /path/to/directory/test.sh /usr/bin/testSH
```

If u arent root user give permission to the shortcut :

> sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/testSH

```
command := "testSH" 
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c",command).Run()
```