# Is it possible to run a gmt script (csh file) using python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this gmt script named map.csh, this file will create a map. I want to run/execute it(map.csh) using python. I tried using subprocess.call but I got an error, "Exec format error"

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['./map.csh'])
```

Comment: Try `subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/env','csh','./map.csh'])` or edit `map.csh` and make the first line `#!/usr/bin/env csh`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it works! Many thanks to you. I've added '/usr/bin/env','csh',

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your script does not appear to be a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), since you **know** it is [csh](/questions/tagged/csh) you can use `env` to invoke it for you. Like,

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/env','csh','./map.csh'])
```

This will search for `csh` (it could be `/bin/csh`, `/usr/bin/csh`, etc).

I still recommend specifying a proper [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009192/how-does-the-shebang-work) as the first line of `map.csh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env csh
```

as that would follow the *principle of least surprise*.