# How do I invoke deno from a shell script?

Tags: shell, deno

I have a script I'd like to run... maybe something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env deno

console.log('hello world');
```

The shebang part is confusing. When I do it as above, with the filename `dev`, I get:

`error: Found argument './dev' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context`

When I try to change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env deno run`

I get

`/usr/bin/env: ‘deno run’: No such file or directory`

Any thoughts on how to pull this off?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009192/how-does-the-shebang-work

Comment: Google suggests that deno needs the executable to have a `.js` or `.ts` extension

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to pass command options to `deno` via `env`, you need the `-S` parameter for env.

For example, the following is the minimal shebang you should use for self-running a script with Deno.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env -S deno run
```

#### Complex Example:

The following script/shebang will run Deno as silently as possible, with all permissions and will assume there is an `import_map.json` file next to the script file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S deno -q run --allow-all --import-map="${_}/../import_map.json"

// get file and directory name
const __filename = import.meta.url.replace("file://", "");
const __dirname = __filename.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/");
```

The lines with `__filename` and `__dirname` will give you variables similar to Node's execution.

---

#### Script Installer

Deno also provides a convenient method for installing a script with it's permissions and dependencies in the configured distribution location.

See: [Deno Manual - Script installer](https://deno.land/manual/tools/script_installer)

#### Stand-Alone Executable

As of Deno 1.6, you can now build stand-alone executables from your script as well.

See: [Deno Manual - Compiler - Compiling Executables](https://deno.land/manual/tools/compiler#compiling-executables)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm trying to write shell scripts using deno / javascript. When I run that install, it just makes a shell script that invokes deno run. Is it possible to do that natively inside a shell script?

Comment: @RandallB - Thanks for clarifying that you already knew about `deno install`.  I updated my answer.

Comment: What if I don't have the `-S` option?

Comment: @Sean then it won't work... to use `/usr/bin/env` with `deno run` as the command, you must have `-S` in between on the shebang line.  I've updated the answer with a more complex example, as well as a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

#### Deno 1.6.0

can compile to a standalone binary / executable file, no need for a custom Shebang:

```
$ deno compile --unstable main.js 
# or add custom output path
$ deno compile --unstable main.js -o /my/path/main
# both create ./main executable (e.g. on Linux)

# execute script directly
$ ./main
```

#### More infos

- [feat: deno compile #8539](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/8539) (PR)
- [Deno v1.6.0](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/tag/v1.6.0) (release info)
- ["deno compile" into executable #986](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/986) (feature request)

Comment: When you provide Deno scripts that should be open-source (like helper scripts in a public repository), there is a need to use a custom Shebang, instead of compilation, definitely.