# Bash script executing once when shouldnt

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to make a bash script to execute a `C++` code multiple times and insert the output on a file, but it execute a single time producing one file with the expected output.

I tried adding a `sleep` command but does not worked.

```
#!/bin/bash
thrd=2
comm="./""Segmentation $thrd"
for i in $(seq 1 30)
do
    echo "${i}"
    exec $comm > outputs/file${i}.txt
    sleep 1s
done
```

Comment: Why do you use `exec`?

Comment: Remove the `exec` command -- it *replaces* the shell that's running your script with the command, hence implicitly terminating the script. BTW, the quoting in `comm` is weird and may not do what you think. Storing commands in variables is generally a bad idea; see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: I started today with it and I saw some content and tried this. I thought the `exec` was mandatory and I didn't even think about trying without. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not relevant to your root problem, but in `bash`, use `for ((i = 1; i <= 30; ++i))` instead of `for i in $(seq 1 30)`. Calling an external command is unnecessary.

Comment: or `for i in {1..30}`.

Comment: Tip: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects this and other common issues.

Answer (score -2):

You could just use a standard shell script.
You can also call sh on a file and it will be interpreted correctly.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 1 30)
do
    echo $i
    sh ./binaryName arg1 arg2 > outputs/file$i.txt
done
```

Comment: Don't use `sh` like this. If the file is a script, set the [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009192/how-does-the-shebang-work) properly, make the file executable, and just run it directly. Using `sh` can cause problems if the script requires bash features, and `sh` is something more basic (Debian, Ubuntu, probably others). If it's not a shell script at all, trying to run it with `sh` will just plain fail.