# cant import python modules

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I am having trouble importing modules into my python projects.  I just switched over to a 2020 Macbook Pro and think that this may have something to do with the problem since I never had problems before.  This mac runs zhs as the default shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import os
import selenium
```

This is the only code that I have written so far (I never used to need to specify that it was a python file with `#!/usr/bin`...)

I get this error message:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`
and I am pretty sure that it isn't a problem with selenium since the same problem occurred when I tried to import `yaml`

When I enter a python shell through the terminal, I can import selenium with no error...

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:48:26) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
>>>
```

Both selenium and my new project are inside `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`
I also tried modifying the `PYTHONPATH` in `zshrc` which didn't seem to help.

I think it should be a quick fix, but I'm not used to how this shell works. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3` and `python3` might be different? What's the output of `type python3`? Try changing the shebang to `/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: Your own project definitely should not be in `site-packages`. How exactly did you install Selenium there?

Comment: @PhuNgo `type python3` results in `python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3` why do I need a shebang in the first place if I named the file `main.py`?

Comment: @PhuNgo your solution is the only one that fixed my problem.

Comment: @MattHyatt shebang is a way to tell the shell which command to run with the file, while filename is not (well except for things like xdg-open for Debian desktop...). Your inintial shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3` uses a different binary than the one you invoked using `python3`, thus the different behaviour. If you specify the shebang as `#/usr/local/bin/python3` it should also work, but `/usr/bin/env python3` is just a safer way to use the same resolved binary from default PATH, i.e. the same python3 you invoked manually

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009192/how-does-the-shebang-work for more information

Answer (score 0):

If you have pip installed you can install selenium like

```
pip install selenium
```

for python3 and based on your permissions you can try

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

Edit

Since you can import selenium with no error on the terminal, your IDE may be pointing to a different installation of Python than where Selenium is installed.

Check where the IDE is pointing and if it's not pointing to where

```
`python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`
```

this is pointing, correct it to that path and you're good to go.

Comment: I already used `pip3` to install it since its in my site-packages...

Comment: Oh, then your IDE might be pointing to a different installation of Python than where Selenium is installed.

Comment: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` is this pointing to the same path?

Comment: well no, but if I did that with python3: `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` then it points to the same path. since I only use python3 for projects that should be ok, right?

Comment: Yes. which ide are you using?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using an ide then while creating a project you should choose a virtual environment where you had installed that selenium

First you must check in which environment you had installed selenium.