# Hashbang won't support parameters with arguments

Tags: shell, escaping, shebang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use multiple arguments with a shebang (i.e. #!)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e)

How can I make a `#!` statement accept a param with arguments? It seems to be lumping them all together as one param instead of splitting on space as usual.

Take this contrived example:

```
$ cat /tmp/echo
#!/bin/echo -n
$ /tmp/echo
/tmp/echo$
```

works great and outputs the filename without a new line at the end. But this one:

```
$ cat /tmp/echo
#!/bin/echo -n hi
$ /tmp/echo
-n hi /tmp/echo
$
```

kills the `-n` arg.

One hack I can do is make another shell script that just execs the first script I want with the params I want, but I'd rather not add extra dependancies if I don't need them.

Comment: For me, the first example works like yours and the second works like you intended (Mac OS X Mountain Lion, bash 3.2.48(1))

Comment: Oh great. It is OS dependent? I'm using CentOS release 5.2

Answer (score 2):

There apparently isn't a POSIX standard for this, but many (possibly most) *nix systems only allow you to send one argument to the program invoked in the shabang.  So using `#!/bin/echo -n hi` is effectively the same as running `/bin/echo "-n hi" /path/to/script`.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/836738) for a more thorough explanation.