# Why won't the python shebang take more than three parameters?

Tags: python, bash, shebang

I'm trying to run a python script with several parameters, the tab warnings,optimize
and verbose parameters, `-t`, `-O` and `-v` respectively. 
    `#!/usr/bin/python -t -O -v` 
This is the error that I get when I try to run it this way, ./script.py in the
terminal.

    `Unknown option: - 
    usage: /usr/bin/python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
    Try python -h' for more information.` 
The script runs well when I have a maximum of one parameter in the shebang.
Is it wrong to pass more than one parameter in a python shebang?

Running the script as 
`python -O -t -v script.py` at the terminal works.

I'm guessing this is a python issue because I have a perl script that has the following
shebang `#!/usr/bin/perl -w -t`  and it runs okay.

The only workaround I came up with was creating a `python_runner.sh` script to invoked
the python interpreter with the three parameters:

```
#!/bin/sh
python -O -t -v $1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e

Comment: Maybe you could try #!/usr/bin/python -tOv

Comment: You should look at argparse

Comment: It works for Perl because the Perl interpreter examines the script's `#!` line.

Comment: @Vyassa's answer is spot on. It works like a charm. So, why does it work differently for python. Keith, do you want to say that python doesn't?

Comment: @Segfault: The kernel examines the `#!` line to determine the name of the interpreter to invoke and the argument(s) to pass to it. Perl additionally examines the `#!` line, if any, after it starts running, useful because it's common to specify options like `-w` and it works even on Windows. I don't know how Python behaves, but my guess is that it just treats the `#!` lines as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the file is called `test.py` and starts with a shebang of:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -t -O -v
```

Then calling `./test.py` would be the equivalent of the command

```
/usr/bin/python '-t -O -V' ./test.py
```

Everything after the first space is treated as one single argument, that's why you can only supply one argument in a shebang. Luckily you can chain shortopts to `-tOv`.

Comment: It depends on the system, as detailed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/827263) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e) mentioned in @ctn's comment.