# How to pass a variable with whitespace to env interpreter

Tags: bash, variables, whitespace, shebang, env

I have this interpreter, which prints the ARGS variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "[$ARGS]"
```

I use this interpreter in another script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ARGS=first interpreter
```

Calling the second script, I get

```
[first]
```

How do I get

```
[first second]
```

?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e regarding the whitespace issue in the Shebang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short of it: **don't rely on being able to pass *multiple* arguments as part of a shebang line**, and **the *one* argument you *can* use must be an *unquoted, single word***.

For more background information, see the question @tholu has already linked to in a comment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/45375).

Thus, I suggest you rewrite your other script to use `bash` as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGS='first second' /usr/bin/env interpreter "$@"
```

- This allows you to use `bash`'s own mechanism for defining environment variables *ad-hoc* (for the command invoked and its children) by prefixing commands with variable assignments, allowing you to use quoting and even define multiple variables.
- Whatever command-line arguments were passed in are passed through to `interpreter` via `"$@"`.