# running nashorn using Shebang does not accept -cp option

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn

I am trying to use a class into a jar using a Nashorn Shebang script with the -cp option (java version "1.8.0_31"). However it does not works. I have perform some test. The following shebang line works:

- #!/usr/bin/jjs -scripting
- #!/usr/bin/jjs -fv (returns nashorn full version 1.8.0_31-b13)

while the following not:

- #!/usr/bin/jjs -cp ./some/lib/lib.jar will return the following error message: **"-cp ./some/lib/lib.jar" is not a recognized option.**
- #!/usr/bin/jjs -scripting -fv will return the error message: **"-scripting -fv" is not a recognized option. Use "-h" or "-help"** to see a list of all supported options"

All options are theoretically valid. The classpath option should also works as seen on http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/setting_the_classpath_for_nashorn .
More info about nashorn and Shebang: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/shell.html#CHDEGHJJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into an issue which doesn’t have anything to do with Nashorn nor Java. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/2711488) the command line argument handling with shebang never was clearly specified and it seems to be a common behavior to treat everything encountered after the first white-space as one single argument.

So one solution would be to write a shell script containing an invocation of `jjs` with the actual arguments and use that shell script as the interpreter in the shebang line of your Nashorn script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -Dnashorn.args=-cp   in a shebang script. See also https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072138

Answer (score 0):

As it appears you want a way to automatically add JARs to your classpath, I'll highlight a little wrapper I've written which allows you to define Maven co-ordinate dependencies (including transitives) to be added to the classpath of your script, so you can write a script using the "# dep" lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jjs-with-deps
#
# The line below is parsed by the jjs-with-deps script to build a new
# classloader in which the script is really executed, including logback
# and its transitive dependencies.
#
# dep:ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2

var log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.example.app.Logger");
log.info("Hello World!");
```

It does require Maven to be installed somewhere on your PATH, and it does slightly increase startup time (but then again, you're already starting up a JVM ;). First invocation of a given script will be much slower while any dependencies are downloaded to the local M2 repository.

Link is https://github.com/stevestorey/jjs-with-deps