# how to set the encoding of stdin in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding

I want my script to be able to take input from stdin where the data might be provided in UTF8 or UTF16 encoding.

something like:

`datasource | my-script -e utf8`

How do I set the external_encoding of stdin ?

Comment: you can do `ruby -Eutf8 script.rb` Is this what you asked ? :)

Comment: This is covered in [the `IO.new` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-new). The information detailed in that method is applicable to other "read" type methods, such as `read`, `gets`, `foreach`.

Comment: @arup: yes, that could work.  But if the script needs to make some decisions before setting the encoding, it will need to follow the suggestion from the Tin Man

Answer (score 2):

In the [first line of the script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) where you define `ruby` as the interpreter, you may add the `--encoding utf-8` parameter in order specify the stdin encoding.

### Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby --encoding utf-8

text = ARGF.read
```

### From `man ruby`:

> ```
>  -E external[:internal]
>  --encoding external[:internal]
>                 Specifies the default value(s) for external encodings and
>                 internal encoding. Values should be separated with colon
>                 (:).
>
>                 You can omit the one for internal encodings, then the
>                 value (Encoding.default_internal) will be nil.
> ```

Comment: This will work great on MacOS but fail on Linux because Linux doesn't handle more than one argument to the shebang. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/195369).

Comment: This still works! Solved a problem for me calling a ruby script from 'Karabiner-Elements.app' or 'Automator.app' on 'macOS Mojave 10.14 that was failing because of an 'invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)' error. Thanks!