# Why does "/usr/bin/env bash -x" only work in command line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, env

I am playing with a `docker CentOS` image, and find executing "`/usr/bin/env bash -x`" command is OK in terminal:

```
bash-4.1# /usr/bin/env bash -x
bash-4.1# exit
+ exit
exit
```

But after writing this command into a script and execute it, it doesn't work, and prompts "`No such file or directory`":

```
bash-4.1# ls -lt a.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 23 May 20 04:27 a.sh
bash-4.1# cat a.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x
bash-4.1# ./a.sh
/usr/bin/env: bash -x: No such file or directory
```

Is there any difference between two methods?

Comment: No there is no difference, make sure the file content is what you think it is (check with `od -c`, I suspect you've got some funny character instead of a space) and that bash is in the path.

Comment: Making `set -x` the first line of the script avoids the need to pass arguments in the hashbang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you only get one parameter to the interpreter which is specified via the "#!" mechanism.  That became "bash -x".

Usually the limitation is more apparent, e.g., using

```
#!/bin/bash -x -i
```

would pass "-x -i" as the parameter, and get unexpected results.

Sven Mascheck comments on this in [his page](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang#splitting) on the topic:

> most systems deliver all arguments as a single string

Answer (score 1):

The shebang line should have at most one argument.
When you give more arguments, they will not be split. You can compare this with the commandline command

```
bash-4.1# /usr/bin/env "bash -x"
```

Comment: Sheebangs support only one parameter in some operating systems (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/297586)). In linux, this yields `/usr/bin/env: ‘"bash -x"’: No such file or directory`. One alternative in this case is to use `set -x` just below the sheebang.