# env with variable setting and python is stuck

Tags: python, shell, debian, env

Not sure why but:

```
   /usr/bin/env IPYTHONDIR=/tmp/.ipython python
```

when running from command line works fine. But stuck as a shabang line:

```
   #!/usr/bin/env IPYTHONDIR=/tmp/.ipython python
```

Environment:
Debian 7.8 x86

Anybody has ideas why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use multiple arguments with a shebang (i.e. #!)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e)

Comment: That should work according to http://linux.die.net/man/1/env, however python is not ipython, instead it runs ipython-script.py (at least on my platform with the Anaconda distribution). Also the shebang line you have will set IPYTHONDIR only in the environment of the process running the script its in.

Comment: @TrisNefzger -- the problem is not with env -- the problem is with the bash handling of `#!`.  bash passes the entire rest of the command line as a single parameter.  It is as if you had typed (on the command line) `/usr/bin/env 'IPYTHONDIR=/tmp/.ipython python'`

Comment: @PatrickMaupin: Ah, I see. Thanks.  What I would do is set any necessary variables on the command line just before the script name and which has shebang '/usr/bin/env/ python'.  If necessary that command line could be wrapped in another script and a script could be written to automate production of such wrappers or apply them on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `#!` passes `IPYTHONDIR=/tmp/.ipython python` as a single parameter to `/usr/bin/env`.

One thing I have used as a workaround is to have another script that sets up variables and then invokes my real program.  It is silly.

Here is some more information:

[How to use multiple arguments with a shebang (i.e. #!)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e)