# Can I specify es6 inside node js file

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, shebang

In order to use es6, we pass the harmony flag in the command line

```
node --harmony myscript.js
```

Is there a way to do this from inside the file, such as `use harmony`?

```
#! /usr/bin/node
use harmony

class MyScript {
    constructor (options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    get options () {
        return this.options
    }
}
```

Comment: No, however, you can do something similar with babel, but it won't affect code that isn't `required` because it does its thing using a require hook.

Comment: `#! /usr/bin/node --harmony`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intention is to do this just so that you can run the script directly like `./myscript.js` you could use this:

```
#!/bin/sh
':' //; exec node --harmony "$0" "$@";

class MyScript {
    constructor (options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    get options () {
        return this.options
    }
}
```

I got the polyglot trick from the blog [Obscure Javascript](http://obscurejavascript.tumblr.com/post/86791947037/node-polyglots).

If your intention is to be able to have another script started without `--harmony` be able to `require` this script, then this trick will not work.

Comment: I wanted to be able to require es6 scripts, so I think as long as my initial file uses this trick it should work fine.

Comment: @Shanimal Yeah, as long as the entry point starts node with `--harmony` every script required from their will be using it.

Comment: Looks like `#! /usr/bin/node --harmony` also works. Is there a difference?

Comment: @Shanimal Nice solution. That will [usually break](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/772035) if you ever want to specify more than one argument, but for your case I would still use it. It's a lot nicer. If you do use, it you should write it as an answer to your question and accept your own answer.