# Something is wrong with `#!`(shebang)(hashbang) in ruby script

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, rubygems

I have a ruby script with following content:

```
#!/data1/thirdparty/ruby/bin/ruby -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0 -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-net-ldap-0.0.4 -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0 -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/i686-linux
```

When I ran the script it throws the following error:

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I took an strace of the program and found this in the strace:

```
open("/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0 -I/data1/thirdparty/enc/encdb.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

So it seems like ruby is not able to handle `-I` properly because it is including it in the file path itself. How can I force the script to use `-I` as an include path directive?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ruby. It is about how to use your operating system properly, and thus belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). It's basically just a variation of "how do I call programs in my shell".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/2988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /data1/thirdparty/ruby/bin/ruby -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0 -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-net-ldap-0.0.4 -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0 -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/i686-linux -x "$0" "$@"

#!ruby
p "this is my ruby code"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would work with [rvm](http://rvm.io) and bundler. You can then call your script with a rvm-wrapper (for example if run in a cron job), or with `bundle exec` for development. You will need to have your `*.gemspec` well configured (for an example run `bundle new mygem` and look at `mygem.gemspec`).

The other possibility would be to write a shell script including

```
/data1/thirdparty/ruby/bin/ruby -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0 -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-net-ldap-0.0.4 -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0 -I/data1/thirdparty/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/i686-linux <yourfile.rb>
```

.

Btw. the `#!` line is called a shebang or hashbang, in case you want to research what happens.