# How can interpreter detect being called from a script as opposed to command line?

Tags: arguments, shebang

As ["is known"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), a script `my-script-file` which starts with

```
#!/path/to/interpreter -arg1 val1 -arg2 val2
```

is executed by `exec` calling `/path/to/interpreter` with ***2***(!) arguments:

1. `-arg1 val1 -arg2 val2`
2. `my-script-file`

(and *not*, as one might naively expect, with 5 arguments

1. `-arg1`
2. `val1`
3. `-arg2`
4. `val2`
5. `my-script-file`

as has been explained in many previous questions, e.g.,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/850781).

My problem is from the POV of an *interpreter developer, **not** script writer*.

### How do I detect from inside the `interpreter` executable that I was called from shebang as opposed to the command line?

Then I will be able to decide whether I need to split my first argument
by space to go from `"-arg1 val1 -arg2 val2"` to `["-arg1", "val1", "-arg2", "val2"]` or not.

The main issue here is script files named with spaces in them.
If I always split the 1st argument, I will fail like this:

```
$ my-interpreter "weird file name with spaces"
my-interpreter: "weird": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, with GNU libc or musl libc, you can use the [aux-vector](https://lwn.net/Articles/519085/) to distinguish the two cases.

Here is some sample code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/auxv.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  printf ("argv[0] = %s\n", argv[0]);
  /* https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html */
  printf ("program_invocation_name = %s\n", program_invocation_name);
  /* http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getauxval.3.html */
  printf ("auxv[AT_EXECFN] = %s\n", (const char *) getauxval (AT_EXECFN));
  /* Determine whether the last two are the same. */
  struct stat statbuf1, statbuf2;
  if (stat (program_invocation_name, &statbuf1) >= 0
      && stat ((const char *) getauxval (AT_EXECFN), &statbuf2) >= 0)
    printf ("same? %d\n", statbuf1.st_dev == statbuf2.st_dev && statbuf1.st_ino == statbuf2.st_ino);
}
```

Result for a direct invocation:

```
$ ./a.out 
argv[0] = ./a.out
program_invocation_name = ./a.out
auxv[AT_EXECFN] = ./a.out
same? 1
```

Result for an invocation through a script that starts with `#!/home/bruno/a.out`:

```
$ ./a.script 
argv[0] = /home/bruno/a.out
program_invocation_name = /home/bruno/a.out
auxv[AT_EXECFN] = ./a.script
same? 0
```

This approach is, of course, highly unportable: Only Linux has the `getauxv` function. And there are surely cases where it does not work well.

Comment: this mess probably explains why unix has single character options and they can be coalesced into a single word like `rm -rf`