# I follow the Posix ERE format but always go true in bash

Tags: regex, bash, posix

I'm following the bash manual and regex guide to do my script, but it doesn't work. The script always accepts all strings or numbers and doesn't follow the format.

This is a valid input: feat: RQ01_HelloWorld.
ty

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash --posix
MSG="$1" 
FEAT=/feat:[[:space:]]RQ[[:digit:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+/
if [[ $MSG=~$FEAT ]]
    then
    echo "yeah"
else
    echo "is wrong"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You need spaces around the operator.

Comment: The `/` aren't needed to surround the regular expression.

Comment: If you use `env` in the shebang line, you can't supply more parameters (such as `--posix`), you have to use `set -o posix` on a separate line instead. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-for-awk-with-a-shebang-i-e). I would have expected POSIX mode to not allow `=~` anyway, but it looks like it does after all.

Comment: POSIX reserves `[[` for implementation-specific purposes. It's behavior is unspecified, which means a shell can use it as it likes without being non-conforming.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems:

1) Unlike in Perl or awk, where the regular expression is contained inside `/.../` as part of the matching operation, `bash` does not use them like this. The `/` are considered part of the regular expression itself.

2) You need whitespace around the `=~` operator so that `[[` sees 3 distinct arguments, rather than a single non-empty string which `[[` considers true.

---

```
FEAT="feat:[[:space:]]RQ[[:digit:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+"

if [[ $MSG =~ $FEAT ]]
```

Comment: i did that and work in regextester but when i run in bash it reject all, i'm using the same words in regextester and bash, maybe you know what happend?

Comment: Does `$MSG` actually have the value you think it does? What happens if you add `[[ $MSG = "RQ01_HelloWorld" ]] || echo "error"` to your script and run it with `RQ01_HelloWorld` as the argument?