# AWK script command line arguments and file input

Tags: unix, awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    print ARGV[1]
}
{
    print $1, $3
}
END{
    print "Done"
}
```

I need to have both command-line arguments and file as input.
I have tried the following and got the error shown:

```
cat users.txt |./temp.awk 3
3
awk: ./temp.awk:4: fatal: cannot open file `3' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

The command-line argument is shown but i cannot seem to find a way to read the file.

Thanks.

Comment: `awk` is expecting a filename instead of 3.  If you need to pass an argument you can use `v=3` instead and drop just report the value.

Comment: @karakfa Can this be done without using v = 3? Thanks for your response.

Comment: No, otherwise `awk` is going to expect a filename.  Only the `x=y` type is treated as variable decleration.

Comment: Put your awk script in a bash script.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you may set `ARGV[1]` or `ARGC` inside the `BEGIN` block:

```
BEGIN {
    print ARGV[1]
    # Empty ARGV[1] so that it is not treated as a filename
    ARGV[1]=""
}
{
    print $1, $3
}
END {
    print "Done"
}
```

---

`man 1p awk`:

> `ARGC` The number of elements in the `ARGV` array.
>
> `ARGV` An array of command line arguments, excluding options and the program argument, numbered from zero to `ARGC`−1.
>
> The  arguments in `ARGV` can be modified or added to; `ARGC` can be altered. As each input file ends, awk shall treat the next non-null element of `ARGV`, up to the current value of `ARGC`−1, inclusive, as the name of the next input file. Thus, setting an element of `ARGV` to null means that it shall not be treated as an input file. The name '`−`' indicates the standard input. If an argument matches the format of an  assignment operand, this argument shall be treated as an assignment rather than a file argument.