# How to run command line awk script (with arguments) as bash script?

Tags: bash, awk

I have an awk script (tst.awk):

```
NR==FNR {
    ids[++numIds] = $1","
    next
}
FNR==1 { numFiles++ }
{
    id = $1
    sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
    vals[id,numFiles] = $0
    gsub(/[^[:space:],]+/,"NA")
    naVal[numFiles] = $0
}
END {
    for ( idNr=1; idNr<=numIds; idNr++) {
        id = ids[idNr]
        printf "%s%s", id, OFS
        for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=numFiles; fileNr++) {
            val = ((id,fileNr) in vals ? vals[id,fileNr] : naVal[fileNr])
            printf "%s%s", val, (fileNr<numFiles ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

That is called on the command line with:

```
awk -f tst.awk master file1 file2 file3 > output.file
```

(note: there can be a variable number of arguments)

How can I change this script, and command line code, to run it as a bash script?

I have tried (tst_awk.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -f "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"

'NR==FNR {
        ids[++numIds] = $1","
        next
    }
    FNR==1 { numFiles++ }
    {
        id = $1
        sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
        vals[id,numFiles] = $0
        gsub(/[^[:space:],]+/,"NA")
        naVal[numFiles] = $0
    }
    END {
        for ( idNr=1; idNr<=numIds; idNr++) {
            id = ids[idNr]
            printf "%s%s", id, OFS
            for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=numFiles; fileNr++) {
                val = ((id,fileNr) in vals ? vals[id,fileNr] : naVal[fileNr])
                printf "%s%s", val, (fileNr<numFiles ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
    }' > output_file
```

called on command line with:

```
./tst_awk.sh master file1 file2 file3
```

I have also tried (tst_awk2.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -f master file1 file2 file3

'NR==FNR {
        ids[++numIds] = $1","
        next
    }
    FNR==1 { numFiles++ }



...

        }
    }
}' > output_file
```

called on command line with:

./tst_awk2.sh

Comment: Use `awk '...' master file1 file2 file3 > output.file` (replace `...` with awk script inside `tst.awk`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-f` needs to be followed by the name of the `awk` script. You're putting the first argument of the shell script after it.

You can use `"$@"` to get all the script arguments, so you're not limited to just 4 arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -f /path/to/tst.awk "$@" > output_file
```

Use an absolute path to the awk script so you can run the shell script from any directory.

If you don't want to use the separate `tst.awk`, you just put the script as the literal first argument to `awk`.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'NR==FNR {
        ids[++numIds] = $1","
        next
    }
    FNR==1 { numFiles++ }
    {
        id = $1
        sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
        vals[id,numFiles] = $0
        gsub(/[^[:space:],]+/,"NA")
        naVal[numFiles] = $0
    }
    END {
        for ( idNr=1; idNr<=numIds; idNr++) {
            id = ids[idNr]
            printf "%s%s", id, OFS
            for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=numFiles; fileNr++) {
                val = ((id,fileNr) in vals ? vals[id,fileNr] : naVal[fileNr])
                printf "%s%s", val, (fileNr<numFiles ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
    }' "$@" > output_file
```

Comment: Very nice! And thanks for the additional information. First time seeing "$@".

Answer (score 0):

you can make your `awk` script executable by adding the shebang

```
#! /bin/awk -f

NR==FNR {
   ids[++numIds] = $1","
   next
}...
```

don't forget to `chmod +x tst.awk`
and run

```
$ ./tst.awk  master file1 file2 file3 > outfile
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001 for some of the reasons why not to do that though.