# How to write multiple commands in a .awk script?

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I want to run all this comands over the same csv file, but  I don't know how to make up an awk script to run all these commands and get a new csv file with all the modifications...

The csv file has this strcuture

```
a,b,c,d,
1,3,4,1
2,2,3,1
...
3,3,1,2
```

And I want to change all the "3" in the second field for the "w" letter, all the "2" in the second field for the "y" letter and all the 3 in the third field for the "fail" word.

To obtain this output:

```
a,b,c,d,
1,w,4,1
2,y,fail,1
...
3,w,1,2
```

The .awk file is:

```
#! /bin/awk -f


BEGIN { FS = "," }
#{print $1","}
{sub(/3/, "w,", $2)}1
{sub(/2/, "y,", $2)}1
{sub(/3/, "fail,", $3)}1



END{print "acabé"}
```

The commands in between are to replace specific numbers of the same field for specific "names"
And in the console I am writing:

```
./name.awk oldfile.csv >newfile.csv
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have modified the post. Hope this helps. Thank you!

Comment: I have modified this and doesn't work :c

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sh
awk '
  BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
  $2 == "3" {$2 = "w"}
  $2 == "2" {$2 = "y"}
  $3 == "3" {$3 = "fail"}
  1
' oldfile.csv
```

Notes:

- use the OFS variable for the "output field separator"
- see how `1` in the awk code only appears once? To see why, click on the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) tag, then click the [Learn more…](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) link.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ","
        map[2][2] = "y"
        map[2][3] = "w"
        map[3][3] = "fail"
    }
    {
        for (fldNr in map) {
            if ($fldNr in map[fldNr]) {
                $fldNr = map[fldNr][$fldNr]
            }
        }
        print
    }
' file
a,b,c,d,
1,w,4,1
2,y,fail,1
...
3,w,1,2
```

By the way -

1. Don't give your executable file names (aka scripts) a suffix like `.awk` - name all of your software based on what it does, not how it does it, including what language it's written in.
2. Don't call awk with a shebang, see
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to run awk commands:

- explicitly:

  ```
   awk 'your code here' filename ...
  ```
- as an executable, shebang-enabled file like the one you provided.
- code from a file:

  ```
   awk -f script.awk filename ...
  ```
- using awk's include (which is similar to python's import and C++' include statements). it can also be used to include files within files.

  ```
   @include script.awk
  ```

  More info [Include Files (The GNU Awk User’s Guide)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Include-Files.html).