# awk script is not running the middle block

Tags: awk

the following script will only run the BEGIN and END blocks:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {print "Hello, World!"}
{ print "Don't Panic" }
END { print "and we're panicking... I told you not to panic.  Did you miss that part?" }
```

and the output is:

```
$ awk -f joint.awk .
  Hello, World!
  and we're panicking... I told you not to panic.  Did you miss that part?
```

the expected output is:

```
$ awk -f joint.awk .
  Hello, World!
  Don't panic
  and we're panicking... I told you not to panic.  Did you miss that part?
```

what's odd is that when I change the middle block to `print $1`, instead of printing a piece of text, it runs as expected when I pass a file in.

Comment: Is there any data on stdin? The middle block is only run when there's data.

Comment: See for example https://ideone.com/tggrLw -- two lines of input, and you get `Don't Panic` printed twice. Zero lines of input, and it never gets printed at all.

Comment: `awk -f joint.awk .` would produce an error message (or warning in GNU awk) about `.` being a directory instead of a file. It's important to read any warning or error messages you get from running tools and to include any such messages when you post questions. In a file that you pass to awk using `-f` any shebang present is ignored as just a comment. If you want to write a shell command that calls awk then a) don't name it with a ".awk" extension, and b) don't call awk with the shebang within it, use a shell in the shebang and call awk from it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner line with explicit no condition gets run *once per line of input on stdin* (or in your input file, if one is explicitly named).

Thus, how many times `Don't Panic` gets printed depends on how much input there is.

See this tested by the following code:

```sh
awkScript=$(cat <<'EOF'
BEGIN {print "Hello, World!"}
{ print "Don't Panic" }
END { print "and we're panicking... I told you not to panic.  Did you miss that part?" }
EOF
)
 
echo "Testing with no input:"
awk "$awkScript" </dev/null
echo
echo "Testing with one line of input:"
awk "$awkScript" <<<"One line of input"
echo
echo "Testing with two lines of input:"
awk "$awkScript" <<<$'First line\nSecond line'
```

...which emits as output:

```
Testing with no input:
Hello, World!
and we're panicking... I told you not to panic.  Did you miss that part?

Testing with one line of input:
Hello, World!
Don't Panic
and we're panicking... I told you not to panic.  Did you miss that part?

Testing with two lines of input:
Hello, World!
Don't Panic
Don't Panic
and we're panicking... I told you not to panic.  Did you miss that part?
```

Comment: Working example is like a picture -- worth 1000 words. I hope he gets the process substitution and heredoc in `awkScript`. A bonus of added learning.

Comment: Thank you!   my understanding of awk's flow was incorrect, as you pointed out.  This fixed it!