# Read a CSV file inside awk script (CLOSED)

Tags: csv, awk

I want to use an AWK script without typing in the terminal the CSV file and instead, call that file from inside my code.

Current Input terminal:

*./script.awk file.csv*

Desired Input Terminal:

*./script.awk*

On the other hand, here is the script I have done so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{print"Filtered Elements:"}
BEGIN{FS=","}

{ if ($8~/.*5.*/ && $2~/.*Sh.*/ && ($3~/.*i.*/ || $4~/.*s.*/)) { print } }
{ if ($3~/.*ra.*/ && $7~/.*18.*/ && $13~/.*r.*/) { print } }
{ if ($5~/.*7.*/ && $2~/.*l.*/ && ($4~/.*Fi.*/ || $12~/20.*/)) { print } }
} **file.csv**
```

---

I aslo tried to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{print"Filtered Elements:"}
BEGIN{FS=","}
BEGIN{
   while (getline < file.csv > 0) {
{ if ($8~/.*5.*/ && $2~/.*Sh.*/ && ($3~/.*i.*/ || $4~/.*s.*/)) { print } }
{ if ($3~/.*ra.*/ && $7~/.*18.*/ && $13~/.*r.*/) { print } }
{ if ($5~/.*7.*/ && $2~/.*l.*/ && ($4~/.*Fi.*/ || $12~/20.*/)) { print } }
   }
```

But either ways an error occurred.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is a correct `getline` loop, except that the file path should be quoted to be treated as a string (and not a variable): `while (getline < "file.csv" > 0) #...`.

Alternatively, you can set the script arguments (including input files and variables) by manipulating `ARGV` and `ARGC` in a `BEGIN` block:

```
BEGIN {
    ARGV[1] = "file.csv"
    ARGC = 2
}

{
    # commands here process file.csv as normal
}
```

Running this as `./script` is the same as if you set the argument with the shell (like `./script file.csv`).

Answer (score 1):

An awk script isn't a command you call, it's a set of instructions interpreted by `awk` where `awk` IS a command you call. What you're trying to do apparently is write a Unix command that's implemented as a shell script which includes a call to awk, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    { print "foo", $0 }
' 'file.csv'
```

Store that in a file named `stuff` (not `stuff.awk` or `stuff.sh` or anything else with a suffix), and then call it as `./stuff` or just `stuff` if the current directory is in your `PATH`.

Though you technically can use a shebang to call awk directly, don't do it - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001.