# Calling awk tool directly by name

Tags: awk

I have written an awk file and made it executable, but do not want to call my awk file in the following manner

```
awk -f tool.awk FILE
```

I just want to call it using

```
tool FILE
```

I made `tool.awk` executable and included

```
#! /bin/awk -f
```

Followed by a link named `tool` to `tool.awk`.

I could then call `tool FILE`

I suppose I can also call `tool FILE` in a bash script as well.  Right?

Comment: I suggest to use a `function` or an `alias`. See `help function` or `help alias`.

Comment: A bash function or an alias to an awk tool without using links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that. Create a shell script named `tool` and call awk from it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk 'script' "${@:--}"
```

If you want to call awk from a bash function named `foo`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo() {
    awk 'script' "${@:--}"
}

foo "${@:--}"
```

File suffixes are meaningless in UNIX but if you create a command that ends in any suffix, e.g. `tool.awk` then that's exactly what you need to type to call it (but don't do that as UNIX commands shouldn't have suffixes).

Comment: Can I do a bash function instead?

Comment: Can I do a bash function instead? How would it look like ?

Comment: I added some code to show how to call awk from a function.

Comment: For what reason do you employ `"${@:--}"`?  Would the awk script need `#!/bin/awk -f` ?

Comment: `"${@:--}"` is a shell construct that means `use any arguments passed in or stdin otherwise` so a script or function can operate on a file or input coming from a pipe.

Comment: `#!/bin/awk -f` is not applicable because, again, you should not call awk with a shebang, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001. Call shell scripts with a shebang that identifies the shell, and just directly call awk from the shell script, as shown in my answer, to avoid unnecessary complications.

Comment: Then try `awk -f ${awkpath}/firefly.awk "${@:--}"` . Good luck.

Comment: @EdMorton, very nice code, cheers sir.

Comment: What does `the ability to separate arguments passed to your shell script into values for the shell to process` mean exactly.  I do have a function that I can call.  Could one call it with arguments relevant to the awk file without restrictions?

Comment: The answer I referenced in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75513719/calling-awk-tool-directly-by-name/75514484?noredirect=1#comment133233519_75514484) explains the issue but if you have any questions about that answer then please leave them under that answer rather than copying some of the content of that answer into a comment here and then asking about it.