# Running a bash function calling awk file

Tags: bash, awk, syntax

I have made a bash function that calls an awk script.

```
edvart-fire ()
 {
  local epath="${HOME}/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/opcon/edvart"
  awk ${epath}/firefly.awk "${@:--}"
 }
```

How can I run this bash function?

Comment: `edvart-fire` .

Comment: `${epath}` should be `"$epath"`, quotes are VERY important in shell, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, get used to using them correctly and don't mistake `${var}` for `"$var"`. You already know how to tell awk to interpret a script file - `awk -f file`, not `awk file`, as you've used and seen in several of your questions and answers, and I just showed you how to call a bash function that calls awk in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75514484/1745001). So it's not clear why you're asking this question.

Comment: @EdMorton Many have used `-f` in calling awk with `awk -f "$epath"/firefly.awk "${@:--}"`.  Whilst you did not use the `-f` option.

Comment: Using `awk -f "$epath"/firefly.awk "${@:--}"` seems necessary.

Comment: @Goncho `-f` is not optional for reading a script from a file, I've never not used it in that context. You may be confusing `awk -f script_file.awk input_file` with `awk 'inline_script' input_file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside the function for a minute ... what are the various ways you would normally call `awk` with `firefly.awk`?

With these in hand you can then figure out how to call the function ...

```
# this:

awk -f "${epath}"/firefly.awk 

# becomes this:

edvart-fire
```

---

```
# this:

awk -f "${epath}"/firefly.awk file1 file2 file3

# becomes this:

edvart-fire file1 file2 file3
```

---

```
# this:

awk -f "${epath}"/firefly.awk -v v1=33 -v v2="abc def" file1 file2 file3

# becomes this:

edvart-fire -v v1=33 -v v2="abc def" file1 file2 file3
```

---

```
# this:

printf "abc\ndef\n" | awk -f "${epath}"/firefly.awk

# becomes this:

printf "abc\ndef\n" | edvart-fire
```

---

This assumes the function is first updated per comments, eg:

```
edvart-fire ()
{  
  local epath="${HOME}/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/opcon/edvart"
  awk -f "${epath}"/firefly.awk "${@:--}"
}
```