# Understanding the use of shebang in awk files

Tags: awk

I want to understand the use of shebang in an awk file named `tool`.

Suppose I have a shebang and make the file executable

```
#! /bin/awk -f
```

I can run the awk script with

```
tool file
```

or with

```
tool -v descriptor=1 file
```

Would it be possible to change `FS`, for instance

```
tool -v descriptor=1 FS="," file
```

Would I call tool the same way inside a bash script?

Would one be able to use

```
awk -f tool -v descriptor=1 file
```

within a bash script ?

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: I need a simple awk file for testing because what I currently have is too complicated.

Comment: This topic is discussed at length in The Awk Programming Language (1988) (https://archive.org/download/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf) e.g. Section 2.5 (p63) and Section 4.2 (p99)

Comment: Regarding `I need a simple awk file for testing because what I currently have is too complicated.` - if you know enough to create a complicated script, why can't you quickly and easily create a simple script? Anyway, here's one: `BEGIN{print "Hello World"}`. Also, don't use a shebang to call awk, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001 as I've referred you to previously.

Comment: Can the shebang difficulties be overcome?

Comment: If you call from bash, the shebang is neglected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the standard syntax when calling `awk` with `-f`:

> awk [-F sepstring] -f progfile [-f progfile]... [-v assignment]... [argument...]

Now, by using `#!/bin/awk -f` as shebang, the `tool` command will be exactly equivalent to:

```bash
/bin/awk -f tool
```

So it's possible to append other `-f profile`, `-v assignment` and file arguments to it; for example:

```bash
tool -F, -v descriptor=1 -v othervar=2 -- file1 file2
```

**notes:**

- You can use `-F,` instead of `-v FS=,`
- `--` is for stopping the parsing of options.

Comment: There seems to exist great dis-agreement between people who use a shebang and those who disapprove of it because of certain difficulties.

Comment: @Goncho It seems to be the case. I personally don't even use `awk -f` in shell scripts because I prefer to be able to see the code that's executed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking look at following 2 snippets from [`awk` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)

> **-f** *program-file*
>
> **--file** *program-file*
>
> Read the AWK program source from the file program-file, instead of from the first command line argument. Multiple **-f** (or **--file**) options may be used.

and

> **-W exec** *file*
>
> **--exec** *file*
>
> Similar to **-f**, however, this is option is the last one processed. This should be used with **#!** scripts, particularly for CGI applications, to avoid passing in options or source code (!) on the command line from a URL. This option disables command-line variable assignments.