# Get value of certain field inside a Variable in AWK

Tags: awk

I have the below data in a variable called MISC , I need to extract from it the value of WOX which is just below it ,in the below example value of WOX is 4:

```
IOT  CND  FO    WZX  END
0         0     0    0
WOX  SR  POW   LIO LIO2
4    00  0
FDR   OTY  M
0
```

I tried several ways but but all were failed to get the value of WOX

Comment: please update the question with some of your coding attempts as well as the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: `echo "$MISC" | awk '$1=="WOX" { getline; print $1; exit}'` ?

Comment: since it appears some keys can have empty values (eg. CND, LIO) can the line below WOX start with whitespace (ie. WOX has no value)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's multi-posted (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/757258/133219) and is a duplicate of the same question the OP asked and got answers to yesterday (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/757165/133219).

Comment: If the questions you've asked so far don't adequately describe the real problem you're facing (as is apparent from some of your comments and the answers you're getting) then ask a new question and this time provide ALL of the information we'd need to know to be able to help you, including a [mcve] including minimal, complete code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

```
$ awk '$1=="WOX"{f=1;next}f{print "WOX="$1;exit}' file
WOX=4
```

Comment: The code working fine with me when this  data exist in a file but in my case I have this data in a Variable called MISC inside my AWK script  and I need to get WOX= to complete my AWK script with it so how can I do that .

Answer (score 2):

Your file isn't valid for all column values as records that follow each set of headings do not have a corresponding value in the next record (e.g. `CND`) Setting that aside, if you want to find the value in the same field as the word searched for, and there is a corresponding value, then you can do so with a fair validation in the following way.

To make the script understandable it has been written in awk script form:

(**note:** edited with suggestions from @EdMorton)

```bash
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  if (!col) {                 ## validate that col variable passed to script
    print "you must pass -v col=\047VAL\047 on the command line with filename"
    exit
  }
}

$0 ~ col {                    ## if record contains col value
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {     ## loop over fields to find field number
    if ($i == col) {
      n = i                   ## set n to field number containing col value
      next                    ## skip to next record
    }
  }
}

n && NF >= n {                ## if n set and record has at least n fields
  print $n                    ## output the value for the corresponding field
  n = 0                       ## reset n zero
}
```

You must pass the `-v col="VOX"` variable to tell the script to provide the heading to look for.

**Example Use/Output**

With the script in the file `readmisccol.awk` and your data in the file `dat/misc.txt`, you would call the script passing the variable, awk script filename and data filename as follows:

```
$ awk -v col="WOX" -f readmisccol.awk dat/misc.txt
4
```

If your text is in a multi-line **shell variable** names `MISC`, then you can simply do:

```
$ echo "$MISC" | awk -v col="WOX" -f readmisccol.awk
4
```

(just pipe to the script and omit the data-file on the end, in bash you can use a *herestring* to provide the variable to awk, e.g. `awk -v col="WOX" -f readmisccol.awk <<< "$MISC"`)

Or if you wanted the value under `SR`, you would do:

```
$ awk -v col="SR" -f readmisccol.awk dat/misc.txt
00
```

or in the `MISC` variable:

```
$ echo "$MISC" | awk -v col="SR" -f readmisccol.awk
00
```

There are many ways to approach this with `awk`. Let me know if you have questions.

Also note, as mentioned in the comments below, calling the `awk` command from within a shell script eliminating the `awk` shebang simplifies passing arguments to the `awk` script. That way you can simply pass the search term as the first positional parameter to the shell script instead of having to provide individual options for `-v` and `-f` on the command line for `awk`.

Comment: The code working fine with me when this  data exist in a file but in my case I have this data in a Variable called MISC inside my AWK script  and I need to get WOX= to complete my AWK script with it so how can I do that .

Comment: Oh, your data is in a MISC *variable*. How is the variable filled? The reason I ask is that while string parsing is possible, since `awk` processes records and fields as input, it is easier to split the data when it is encountered by `awk` rather than trying to process it as a multi-line variable once it is already inside of awk. Is the variable an **awk variable** or a **shell variable**? If it is a shell variable, just to `echo "$var" | awk -v col="WOX" -f readmisccol.awk` (omit the datafile) Let me know and I'll work further on splitting it if there is no other option.

Comment: Requiring the user of the command to know that it's implemented in awk is one of the reasons why you shouldn't call awk in a shebang and another being the problem you ran into where add `-v ...` became problematic, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001. If you don't do that then you could make the user interface `readmisccol WOX dat/misc.txt` and internally map the command arguments to awk arguments `col="$1"; shift; awk -v col="$col" '...' "${@:--}"`. That makes the user interface simpler and allows you to replace awk with perl or anything else without changing where its called.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton, all better ways to skin the cat! And, yes, it's much easier just to pull the call to `awk` into the bash script and process the positional parameters in the call to `awk`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sorry to say something unrelated. can I have your email address.

Comment: @jian - sure, its drankinatty at gmail. I'll keep an eye on the account.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way

```
awk 'BEGIN{misc="IOT  CND  FO    WZX  END\n0         0     0    0  \nWOX  SR  POW   LIO LIO2 \n4    00  0              \nFDR   OTY  M            \n0                       \n"}END{split(misc, lines, /\n/);for(i=1;i<=length(lines);i+=1){if(match(lines[i],/WOX */)){wox=substr(lines[i+1],RSTART,RLENGTH)}};print wox}' emptyfile
```

gives output

```
4
```

Note: `BEGIN` is used just to set misc variable, actual processing is in `END`. Explanation: I use [String functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), firstly I split multiline variable `misc` into lines by splitting at newlines. Then I process subsequent lines using `for` loop. If there is `WOX` followed by zero-or-more spaces `RSTART` and `RLENTH` are set, which I use to get substring of next line (note +1 after i) under it and place that inside variable named `wox`. Disclaimer: if there are multiple `WOX` then 1st one in last line with `WOX` wins.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it is didn't give my any output .