# Purpose of #!/usr/bin/python3 shebang

Tags: python, scripting

I have noticed this in a couple of scripting languages, but in this example, I am using python. In many tutorials, they would start with `#!/usr/bin/python3` on the first line. I don't understand why we have this.

- Shouldn't the operating system know it's a python script (obviously it's installed since you are making a reference to it)
- What if the user is using a operating system that isn't unix based
- The language is installed in a different folder for whatever reason
- The user has a different version. Especially when it's not a full version number(Like Python3 vs Python32)

If anything, I could see this breaking the python script because of the listed reasons above.

Comment: I come to  this question just to copy the shebang string.

Comment: @omerjerk What an coincidence, Me too. ^^

Answer (score 401, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/python3` is a [**shebang line**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

A shebang line defines where the interpreter is located. In this case, the `python3` interpreter is located in `/usr/bin/python3`. A shebang line could also be a `bash`, `ruby`, `perl` or any other scripting languages' interpreter, for example: `#!/bin/bash`.

Without the shebang line, the operating system does not know it's a python script, even if you set the execution flag (`chmod +x script.py`) on the script and run it like `./script.py`. To make the script run by default in python3, either invoke it as `python3 script.py` or set the shebang line.

You can use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` for portability across different systems in case they have the language interpreter installed in different locations.

Comment: So `#! /usr/bin/env python3` should be chosen over `#! /usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: @winklerrr Yes, it's more widely used.

Comment: What do you mean by setting the "execution flag" ?

Comment: @Papaya-Automaton `chmod +x`.

Comment: `Question` @Jin; if we have **shebangs** ; do we have **manbangs** too? o_O  Jokes aside,  this is just a flawlessly brilliant answer; thanks a lot!

Answer (score 30):

That's called a hash-bang. If you run the script from the shell, it will inspect the first line to figure out what program should be started to interpret the script.

A non Unix based OS will use its own rules for figuring out how to run the script. Windows for example will use the filename extension and the `#` will cause the first line to be treated as a comment.

If the path to the Python executable is wrong, then naturally the script will fail. It is easy to create links to the actual executable from whatever location is specified by standard convention.

Answer (score 14):

This line helps find the program executable that will run the script. This shebang notation is fairly standard across most scripting languages (at least as used on grown-up operating systems).

An important aspect of this line is specifying *which* interpreter will be used. On many development-centered Linux distributions, for example, it is normal to have several versions of python installed at the same time.

Python 2.x and Python 3 are not 100% compatible, so this difference can be very important. So `#! /usr/bin/python` and `#! /usr/bin/python3` are not the same (and neither are quite the same as `#! /usr/bin/env python3` as noted elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 10):

To clarify how the shebang line works for windows, from the [3.7 Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html):

- If the first line of a script file starts with #!, it is known as a “shebang” line. Linux and other Unix like operating systems have native support for such lines and they are commonly used on such systems to indicate how a script should be executed.
- The Python Launcher for Windows allows the same facilities to be used with Python scripts on Windows
- To allow shebang lines in Python scripts to be portable between Unix and Windows, the launcher supports a number of ‘virtual’ commands to specify which interpreter to use. The supported virtual commands are:

  - /usr/bin/env python

    - The /usr/bin/env form of shebang line has one further special property. Before looking for installed Python interpreters, this form will search the executable PATH for a Python executable. This corresponds to the behaviour of the Unix env program, which performs a PATH search.
  - /usr/bin/python
  - /usr/local/bin/python
  - python

Answer (score 7):

1. And this line is **how**.
2. It is ignored.
3. It will fail to run, and should be changed to point to the proper location. Or `env` should be used.
4. It will fail to run, and probably fail to run under a different version regardless.

Answer (score 4):

**The `exec` system call of the Linux kernel understands shebangs (`#!`) natively**

When you do on bash:

```
./something
```

on Linux, this calls the `exec` system call with the path `./something`.

This line of the kernel gets called on the file passed to `exec`: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.8/fs/binfmt_script.c#L25

```
if ((bprm->buf[0] != '#') || (bprm->buf[1] != '!'))
```

It reads the very first bytes of the file, and compares them to `#!`.

If the comparison is true, then the rest of the line is parsed by the Linux kernel, which makes another `exec` call with path `/usr/bin/python3` and current file as the first argument:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py
```

and this works for any scripting language that uses `#` as a comment character.

And analogously, if you decide to use `env` instead, which you likely should always do to work on systems that have the `python3` in a different location, notably [`pyenv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960805/apt-get-install-for-different-python-versions/59268046#59268046), see also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my), the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

ends up calling analogously:

```
/usr/bin/env python3 /path/to/script.py
```

which does what you expect from `env python3`: searches `PATH` for `python3` and runs `/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py`.

And yes, you can make an infinite loop with:

```
printf '#!/a\n' | sudo tee /a
sudo chmod +x /a
/a
```

Bash recognizes the error:

```
-bash: /a: /a: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

`#!` just happens to be human readable, but that is not required.

If the file started with different bytes, then the `exec` system call would use a different handler. The other most important built-in handler is for ELF executable files: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.8/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L1305 which checks for bytes `7f 45 4c 46` (which also happens to be human readable for `.ELF`). Let's confirm that by reading the 4 first bytes of `/bin/ls`, which is an ELF executable:

```
head -c 4 "$(which ls)" | hd
```

output:

```
00000000  7f 45 4c 46                                       |.ELF|
00000004
```

So when the kernel sees those bytes, it takes the ELF file, puts it into memory correctly, and starts a new process with it. See also: [How does kernel get an executable binary file running under linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352535/how-does-kernel-get-an-executable-binary-file-running-under-linux/31394861#31394861)

Finally, you can add your own shebang handlers with the `binfmt_misc` mechanism. For example, you can add a [custom handler for `.jar` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667830/running-a-jar-file-without-directly-calling-java). This mechanism even supports handlers by file extension. Another application is to [transparently run executables of a different architecture with QEMU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41889/how-can-i-chroot-into-a-filesystem-with-a-different-architechture).

I don't think [POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/what-is-the-meaning-of-posix/31865755#31865755) specifies shebangs however: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346214/32558 , although it does mention in on rationale sections, and in the form "if executable scripts are supported by the system something may happen". macOS and FreeBSD also seem to implement it however.

**`PATH` search motivation**

Likely, one big motivation for the existence of shebangs is the fact that in Linux, we often want to run commands from `PATH` just as:

```
basename-of-command
```

instead of:

```
/full/path/to/basename-of-command
```

But then, without the shebang mechanism, how would Linux know how to launch each type of file?

Hardcoding the extension in commands:

```
 basename-of-command.py
```

or implementing PATH search on every interpreter:

```
python3 basename-of-command
```

would be a possibility, but this has the major problem that everything breaks if we ever decide to refactor the command into another language.

Shebangs solve this problem beautifully.

See also: [Why do people write #!/usr/bin/env python on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)

Answer (score 3):

Actually the determination of what type of file a file is very complicated, so now the operating system can't just know.  It can make lots of guesses based on -

- extension
- UTI
- MIME

But the command line doesn't bother with all that, because it runs on a limited backwards compatible layer, from when that fancy nonsense didn't mean anything. If you double click it sure, a modern OS can figure that out- but if you run it from a terminal then no, because the terminal doesn't care about your fancy OS specific file typing APIs.

Regarding the other points. It's a convenience, it's similarly possible to run

`python3 path/to/your/script`

If your python isn't in the path specified, then it won't work, but we tend to install things to make stuff like this work, not the other way around.  It doesn't actually matter if you're under *nix, it's up to your shell whether to consider this line because it's a `shellcode`.  So for example you can run `bash` under Windows.

You can actually ommit this line entirely, it just mean the caller will have to specify an interpreter.  Also don't put your interpreters in nonstandard locations and then try to call scripts without providing an interpreter.