# simple python password prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've finally decided to start learning python as my first language and so far i love it. I;m using python3 along with IDLE3. When writing a simple password prompt im running into a problem :/  script is as follows.

```
import sys

password = input("Enter your password: ")
if password != "pword" :
    sys.exit()
print("Password correct")
```

Now when i run the script and enter pass as the password i get the following error:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# python password1.py
Enter your password: pword
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "password1.py", line 2, in <module>
password = input("Enter your password: ")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pword' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys, it's appreciated.

Comment: The code you show has `'pword'` (notice the quotes, a string) but the error suggests you have `pword` (a bareword, undefined variable). If you really do have quotes around it try clearing out your `__pycache__` folder.

Comment: use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: You're actually using Python 2, aren't you?

Comment: sorry the script didnt come out like i meant it to here's a better view

             import sys
password = input("Enter your password: ")
if password != "pword" :
    sys.exit()
print("Password correct!")

Comment: Yes. use `raw_input`

Comment: im using python 3.5.2

Comment: @Adam59600 No you're not.

Comment: how would i use raw_input?

Comment: Run `python -V` in your console and tell us what is the output

Comment: IDLE says python-3.5.2...?

Comment: python -V shows python 2.7.12+

Comment: Then you are using python 2.7.12 :), maybe you have two versions of python installed

Comment: @Adam59600 So use `raw_input`. Where did you get the notion you were using 3+

Comment: @AndrewL. well I mean, he actually answered that already.

Comment: i do have python 3 tho i can termal python3 and get a window

Comment: So you probably have two versions installed

Comment: @Adam59600 are you on Windows? You may have to change your file association for .py files to use `py -3` instead of `python`

Comment: no im on debian via usb persistence. i could boot over to windows and make my life alot easier but im forcing myself to learn linux and python pretty much at the same time.. How would i change the file association then? I'm sorry im so dumb, please don't hurt me!

Comment: @Adam59600 Use a "shebang." Start your script with `#!/usr/bin/python3`. [See more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670303/purpose-of-usr-bin-python3) and run it with `./myscript.py`

Comment: @Adam59600 or alternatively, run it with `python3 myscript.py` (instead of `python myscript.py` which is ALWAYS py2 on *nix systems or `./myscript.py` without the shebang)

Comment: @Adam Smith  Thank you so much i'd be lost without your help!

Comment: The end result of my script is:

            import sys
password = input("Enter your password: ")
if password != "pword" :
    print("incorrect password")
    sys.exit()
print("Password correct!")

Answer (score 1):

One of two things is happening. Either

A) your copy is wrong, and your script actually reads

```
...
if password != pword:  # note the lack of quotes
...
```

or B) you're using Python 2

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
# should show 3.x.y per your question, but if it's showing 2.x.y, that'd be why
```

The reason Python2 vs Python3 matters is that the `input` builtin works differently between the two. In Python2, `input` tries to resolve user input within the namespace, e.g.

```
# Python2
>>> foo = "bar"
>>> spam = input("enter something: ")
enter something: foo
>>> print(spam)
bar
```

While Python3 just returns the input as a string

```
# Python3
>>> foo = "bar"
>>> spam = input("enter something: ")
enter something: foo
>>> print(spam)
foo
```

Comment: "_Should I answer it?
No, not if you think it's a duplicate._"
[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Comment: @Polikdir right, but at the time I answered this, it wasn't clear that it was a duplicate. That only came out over the course of the comments with OP. Note that there are two possibilities for what's causing the issue in my answer! :)

Comment: password = raw_input("Enter your password: ")   worked! Thank you guys

Comment: @adam59600 note that that solution is just writing py2 code. MUCH better to keep the code you had and run python 3 instead!

Comment: im not sure why my system deafualts to py2.. ive installed py3 did ./configure  then make then make install and everything installed successfully... is this a file association issue as previously stated?

Comment: @adam59600 no that's normal on nix. `python` always points at py2. Read my comments on your question

Comment: @Polikdir  excuse my ignorance for not using the search function first. i didn't realize this is a duplicate.