# How to specify which version of python to use in npm python-shell node.js

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, node-modules

I want to invoke a python script in a js file using python-shell. However the script requires python3 and py2 is always used, while my local development has both py2 and 3 installed. How do i specify it to use python3 instead?

```
app.get('/run_py', (req, res)=>{
    var myPythonScriptPath = 'script.py';

    // Use python shell
    var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
    var pyshell = new PythonShell("pyscripts/test.py");

    pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
        // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
        console.log(message);
    });

    // end the input stream and allow the process to exit
    pyshell.end(function (err) {
        if (err){
            throw err;
        };

        //console.log('finished');
    });
});
```

My py script looks like:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raise Exception("Must be using Python 3")

print('running test.py')
print (sys.version_info[0])
```

It always uses python 2.7 when running locally.

Moreover, when I push my code to heroku server which use python 3.6 as default. The scripts runs perfectly...

Any insights? please?

EDIT: I saw you can specify the python path in the PythonShell.run as a parameter.. But what if different platforms say heroku and my local machine has different path to python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the python-shell documentation](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell), you can specify the python interpreter path in the `PythonShell` options. There are two things you need to do:

1. Ensure that python3 is installed on your local system (might need `pip install python3` or something similar)
2. Change the python path to point to python3 (might just need to be `/usr/bin/env python3`

EDIT: In response to your edit, if both of your node services are running on Linux, you should be able to use `/usr/bin/env python3`. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670338/3277713) for resolves across systems.

Comment: Thanks but what if the server has different python path than my local machine? Sorry I am pretty new i don't know what the best practice is..

Comment: See my edit :) you can use `env` to point a single path that will resolve correctly on both systems

Comment: It seem like i can simply use `option = {pythonPath: 'python3'}`

Comment: Can you expand on how to use `env`? Like `option = {pythonPath: '/usr/bin/env python3'}` ? it doesn't seem right.

Comment: The both `option = {pythonPath: 'python3'}` and `option = {pythonPath: '/usr/bin/env python3'}` will work, the latter is more explicit. See the SO response I linked in my edit!

Answer (score 0):

Update: As of August 7, 2018, python3 is the default pythonPath.

https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell/blob/f3b64d3307d8dc15eb9c071d8aa774c1e7d5b2d7/index.ts#L94