# Run Flask using python3 not python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

How can you run Flask app which uses a specific version of python?

On my env "python" = python2.7 and "python3" = python3.6. I have installed Flask using pip3. I start the app with `FLASK_APP=app.py flask run`. It uses python2.7 to execute, I would like it to use python3.6.

Also tried adding `#!flask/bin/python3` to app.py, but it did not have an effect.

Comment: Put it in a virtualenv that was created for Python 3.

Comment: have you considered using Docker?

Comment: `#!flask` isn't a thing. Try `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) lets you create isolated python environments with different versions (this is the way I would recommend)
2. You can put `#!/usr/bin/python3` on top of your python file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670303/purpose-of-usr-bin-python3))
3. Or you can start your script with `python3 script.py`
4. As mentioned in the comments above you can also start your script inside a [Docker container that hosts a python3 installation](https://www.civisanalytics.com/blog/using-docker-to-run-python/)

Comment: Thank you, `#!/usr/bin/python3` worked. I will put it in virtualenv at some point.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was:

1. `which flask`, to find flask binary executable path (in my case `/home/myuser/.local/bin/flask`
2. edit `/home/myuser/.local/bin/flask`, changing the first line from `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python3`

In summary, making flask use python3, regardless of which shebang was specified in other scripts, since those scripts are not the entrypoint of execution, but flask is. I didn't have to change the shebang in any of my scripts, just the flask executable.