# How to setup custom python version for your flask app to run?

Tags: python, flask

I have three python versions installed in my system:

1. `python3.5`
2. `python3.6`
3. `python3.8`

I have created a flask app which is `waterchain.py`

and setup my `.flaskenv` as shown below:

```
FLASK_APP=waterchain.py
FLASK_ENV=production
```

Now when I do a flask run, I get this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'`

This is because although I have installed all the modules in `python3.6` by default flask run chooses to run it on latest python version that is `python3.8`. Now in order to run all those apps, I would have to reinstall all the pip dependencies for `python3.8`. When I do a `py -3.6 waterchain.py` everything runs smoothly. Can someone point me a way to change default python running version for my flask app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Flask using python3 not python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49255283/run-flask-using-python3-not-python)

Comment: "When I do a py -3.6 waterchain.py everything runs smoothly." -- doesn't that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this and with any other python project is to use virtual environments, as with them you can install/uninstall packages and manage their versions easily, thus being also able to choose which version you'd actually like to use.

Here you have a link to the documentation of how to use virtual environments: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Also, I prefer using pipenv, if you'd like to look into it, here you can find how: https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/

And a video tutorial if you'd really want someone talking while explaining and having a feel of how it looks like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk

Basically, with virtual environments you're setting up python packages **per project**, so that you can use for example different python versions, or different versions of packages for different projects. It's an easy to learn thing and really useful.