# Execute .JAR by name without specifying 'java -jar' command options

Tags: java, jar, manifest.mf

Is it possible to execute a jar file by simply typing the jar name into the command line? Is there anything I can add to the manifest to achieve this?

Ie. `jarname.jar` instead of `java -jar jarname.jar`

Comment: well, you can wrap your jar into some script. What OS is it?

Comment: I agree that writing a .sh or .bat file would be the simplest and best approach

Comment: Create a `Batch File` if using `Windows` or use a `shell script` for unix machines :-) Example (batch file) `@ECHO OFF<Press ENTER>set /p fileName="Enter JAR to execute"<Press ENTER> java -jar %fileName%.jar`. That's it now double click this batch file and run the jar.

Comment: @nIcEcOw If you make an executable jar you can run it just by double-clicking the jar itself.

Comment: @JasonC : LOL, too true. I was just thinking about this very thingy, as to __WHAT WAS I THINKING, while commenting on the question?__ :-)

Comment: If you want an cross-platform example startup script, I've grabbed the outputs from Gradle (a build tool) when it packages things. They are made to work in most circumstances and therefore are very long, so I put them up as a gist: https://gist.github.com/flaviut/9180497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really avoid that easily.

A common strategy is to deploy an executable startup script with your application; one per platform since this is platform specific (e.g. an executable shell script for Linux, and a batch script for Windows). Standard shell scripting techniques can be used to pass command line parameters to the script on to your application.

Note that there are some clever platform-specific tricks, such as the Linux one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1671124/616460) (and I'm not certain but it may be possible to make *all* jars executable on the command line with some dirty registry hacks on Windows); but if you are going for platform-independence (and you don't want to have to post-process your JARs after a build), deploying a wrapper script is the way to go.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was just hoping for an inbuilt wrapper rather than an OS specific script one but that's alright. :)